# How do i figure out which process is causing a beeping sound?

Tags: 10.04, sound, log

I'm using 10.04 and some process is periodically causing a sound (more like a chime than a beep) and I can't figure out what it is. I don't want to turn off system beeps or sound in general, I just want to get this particular beeping to stop.

I have tried looking in `/var/log/user.log` and `/var/log/syslog` but dont see anything obvious other than perhaps:

```
Jan 13 15:45:16 4myle-66131 pulseaudio[5606]: ratelimit.c: 130 events suppressed
```

However searches on this haven't turned up anything enlightening.

How can I track down which process is making these sounds?

Comment: @david-lebauer why are you offering a bounty on an unsupported version of Ubuntu? 10.04 is long past support.

Comment: @ElderGeek I assumed the answer would be the same, and didn't want to repost a duplicate. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Sound Preferences, and go to the last tab: Applications.

If an application is making any noise, it will probably be listed here. Take a look and see if the application is there (it may be there only when the sound is heard, so keep looking for a while).

Comment: the only application it shows is Spotify, but I don't see any outstanding issues online where Spotify constantly beeps...

Comment: Saw the problem app there. looks like before I wasn't opening it fast enough. "asla plugin chrome"

Comment: Never found the underlying issue with the asla plugin and chrome, but Sound Preferences remembers the muting toggle for applications so muting "alsa plugin chrome" when it showed up meant no more beeps. Thanks @jorge!

Comment: Where is "Sound Preferences" in KDE? Or is there another way, e.g. via `lsof`? I had the same sort of ringing sound once a second right after boot on 14.04 just now. Bizarre. Finally just went away after 20 minutes..... Next time I'll also just look for the alsa plugin chrome - thanks @allen....

Comment: @nealmcb The mixer should fully support pulse audio. It's called kmix, but I don't know if it fully support that in 14.04. You can also try pavucontrol instead, the default pulse audio graphical mixer-controller.

Comment: @nealmcb from the terminal run `unity-control-center` and click **Sound**. In the middle of the window should be a series of tabs. Click **Applications**

Comment: @allen Excellent - thank you!! `unity-control-center` will help me with more than just sound settings, I bet....